# How to generate FastDDS message files from a .idl file that imports structs from others .idl files

Tags: c++, import, idl, data-distribution-service

I have a few message files that are stored like this:

```
msgs/
  core/
   - core.idl
   - geoCore.idl
  geometry/
   - shape.idl
```

I'm tring to generate the corresponding fastDDS message files for shape.idl (shape.cxx, shape.h, shape.PubSubType.h, ...). However, shape.idl file is using structs that are defined only in core.idl and geoCore.idl. .

To adress that, shape.idl include the other two files:

```
#include "core.idl"
#include "geoCore.idl"
```

So,now, when I run `fastddsgen /dir/to/geometry/shape.idl`, I get :

```
WARNING (File shape, Line 8): Annotation topic not supported. Ignoring...
./dir/to/geometry/shape.idl:10:12: error: 'Core' was not defined previously
./dir/to/geometry/shape.idl.idl:11:12: error: 'Point' was not defined previously
./dir/to/geometry/shape.idl.idl:12:12: error: 'Ori' was not defined previously
```

where `Core` and `Point` are defined in `core.idl`, and `Ori` is defined in `geoCore.idl`

I even add the flag `-I` and included the dependencies folder, but the result is the same.
ex:

```
fastddsgen /dir/to/geometry/shape.idl -I /dir/to/core/
```